# C# / Windows Firewall - Remove IP from rule

Tags: c#, windows-firewall

I wrote a `C#` program that adds IPs to the `Windows Server 2008 Firewall` rule to block them.

The command looks like this and is executed as description in the accepted answer from [this thread here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

```
pushd advfirewall firewall
set rule name="BlockedIPs" new remoteip="1.2.3.4" action=block protocol=any dir=in
popd
```

However I'd also like to unblock them again. I have little experience with this. What's the command, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more of a question for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). However, to answer your question, the command is called delete. Look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx) for a complete reference to all the firewall commands.

To delete a rule:

```
delete rule name="BlockedIPs"
```

Comment: Hmm thanks. But what if I just want to delete 1 IP from that rule?

Comment: Server Fault helped. Didn't know about it!